# Using React.memo with hooks for controlled inputs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm providing some form functionality from a custom React hook. This hook has some functionality similar to Formik (but this is really basic stuff).

```
function useFormValidation(initialState, validate) {
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState(initialState);
  const [errors, setErrors] = React.useState({});
  const [isSubmitting, setSubmitting] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (isSubmitting) {
      const noErrors = Object.keys(errors).length === 0;
      if (noErrors) {
        console.log("authenticated!", values.email, values.password);
        setSubmitting(false);
      } else {
        setSubmitting(false);
      }
    }
  }, [errors]);

  function handleChange(event) {
    setValues({
      ...values,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  }

  function handleBlur() {
    const validationErrors = validate(values);
    setErrors(validationErrors);
  }

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const validationErrors = validate(values);
    setErrors(validationErrors);
    setSubmitting(true);
  }

  return {
    handleSubmit,
    handleChange,
    handleBlur,
    values,
    errors,
    isSubmitting
  };
}
```

The form is the following:

```
function Register() {
  const {
    handleSubmit,

    handleChange,
    handleBlur,
    values,
    errors,
    isSubmitting
  } = useFormValidation(INITIAL_STATE, validateAuth);
  // const [email, setEmail] = React.useState("");
  // const [password, setPassword] = React.useState("");

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>Register Here</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Input
          handleChange={handleChange}
          handleBlur={handleBlur}
          name="email"
          value={values.email}
          className={errors.email && "error-input"}
          autoComplete="off"
          placeholder="Your email address"
        />
        {errors.email && <p className="error-text">{errors.email}</p>}
        <Input
          handleChange={handleChange}
          handleBlur={handleBlur}
          value={values.password}
          className={errors.password && "error-input"}
          name="password"
          // type="password"
          placeholder="Choose a safe password"
        />
        {errors.password && <p className="error-text">{errors.password}</p>}
        <div>
          <button disabled={isSubmitting} type="submit">
            Submit
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And the memoized component is the next:

```
function Input({
  handleChange,
  handleBlur,
  name,
  value,
  className,
  autoComplete,
  placeholder,
  type
}) {

  return (
    <input
      onChange={handleChange}
      onBlur={handleBlur}
      name={name}
      value={value}
      className={className}
      autoComplete={autoComplete}
      placeholder={placeholder}
      type={type}
    />
  );
}

function areEqual(prevProps, nextProps) {
  console.log(`
    prevProps: ${JSON.stringify(prevProps.value)}
    nextProps: ${JSON.stringify(nextProps.value)}
  `);
  return prevProps.value === nextProps.value;
}
const useMemo = (component, propsAreEqual) => {
  return memo(component, propsAreEqual);
};
export default useMemo(Input, areEqual);
```

I enter some text into the first input. Then, when I switch to the second Input and start typing, the first input loses the value. It's like the form is not rendering the LAST MEMOIZED input, but prior versions instead. 
I'm a React beginner and can't figure out the solution. Any help please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the updater form of `setState` which takes a function:

```
function handleChange(event) {
  // event.target wont be available when fn is run in setState
  // so we save them in our own local variables here
  const { name, value } = event.target;

  setValues(prev => ({
    ...prev,
    [name]: value
  }));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! With your suggestion, I ended up reading some related stuff. I was reading this [beware-react-setstate-is-asynchronous](https://medium.com/@wereHamster/beware-react-setstate-is-asynchronous-ce87ef1a9cf3), but probably it's not the case. (or is it?) Can you give me some link for further reading?

Comment: This can be very useful [https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/functional-setstate-is-the-future-of-react-374f30401b6b/](functional setState)

Answer (score 1):

Your `areEqual` method translates to

> Re-render my Input ONLY when the `value` changes.

But in reality, your `handleChange` function from the hook is also changing. Also, you use the same `handleChange` for both the inputs. So, the `Input` "remembers" only the `handleChange` from the last time `value` had changed and since `handleChange` is tracking `values` via closure, it in-turn "remembers" the `values` when it was created.

Changing your `areEqual` method (or completely omitting it) to verify a change in `handleChange`, will solve your problem.

```
function areEqual(prevProps, nextProps) {
  return (
    prevProps.value === nextProps.value &&
    prevProps.handleChange === nextProps.handleChange
  );
}
```

A codesandbox of the solution [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-voice-3y88e)

Comment: "handleChange" is not part of the Input props! "handleChange" is part of the hook instead. So there could not be "prevProps.handleChange === nextProps.handleChange".

Comment: @JoseMiguelOchoa `Input` clearly has a `handleChange` prop. Did you try out my solution?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I see now what you're saying. I tried your solution. I should've mentioned that I use a memoized input because the form needs to avoid unnecessary renders. In my real project form, I have a lot of selects and lots of inputs. It gets the form really unresponsive (every select fetchs data from a Graphql endpoint using Apollo) if I don't memoized the inputs and selects.

Comment: There are many subtle bugs that can show up in your current implementation. Your Input component will not re-render if any prop other than `value` changes. It might work out now, but you never know later. Just keep that in mind.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I'll do it more general so it can accept more values. Thanks.